# Delete ghost image in a drag with ie10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-10, drag

I'm migrating a website Jquery IE9 to IE10. And I've seen IE10 leaves a ghost image when I drag on the web. The application is on production, so I can not change the current D&D (for images on IE9)

Is there any way to remove the ghost image?

This is the image tag:

```
<img src = "stylesheets/static/hand01.png" title = "'+ output [i.ToString ()] [' number '] +'" draggable = "true" onmousedown = "drag1 (event, this.title) ">
```

I tried to change the event, but I saw that IE10 does not accept the event.dataTransfer.setDragImage :( and I do not know if would be possible to do it by css

Comment: I'm not positive I understand the question. What do you mean when you say "I'm migrating a website Jquery IE9 to IE10"? & basically you're trying to get rid of the slightly transparent clone of the image that you're dragging? If you don't want them to be able to drag any images at all just do `$('img').on('mousedown dragstart drag', function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;});`

Comment: Currently the customer is using the page in IE9, so had to use a D&D like image to image. Now they want to switch to IE10 but they want to keep everything the same as IE9, so we must modify the code for use in IE10 (quick change). Directly we have several erroneous visual effects, so we put the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` in the `<head>` to fix it. The only visual error is that "slightly transparent clone of the image" that appears when I'm dragging. We need to move an image to another image so we can not remove directly the option to drag, just remove the clone image.